# Batch File To Execute Between Specific Times

Tags: batch-file, time, command, schedule, hour

I have a batch file which is deployed to machines as soon as they're able to receive the file (which is a variable - as some may be offline, busy, or delayed), but it should only run it the current local time is inside a specified window.

Eg, only between 12am & 2am.

I do have the following working with PM times- But apparently it will not execute if I specify any single (or double) digit AM hours here (such as 1am through to 9am).

```
@echo off
SET hour=%time:~0,2%
SET shouldrun=True

IF %hour% leq 23 SET shouldrun=False
IF %hour% geq 02 SET shouldrun=False

IF "%shouldrun%"=="False" (
        echo Outside Update Schedule
        EXIT /B 1
)

IF "%shouldrun%"=="True" (
        @TASKKILL /f /im some.exe > nul 2>&1
        @timeout /t 4 > nul
         - do things here -
        @timeout /t 2 > nul
        shutdown -r -f -y -t 2
        EXIT /B 0
)
```

Comment: What is wrong with running a batch file using the task scheduler between those times? At the moment, if your script runs before eleven PM, it will close, and would therefore have to be started again. I don't see any benefit in creating a script or executable to continually run restarting that batch file, until a particular time range is reached, when there's already a built-in facility for doing so.

Comment: The nature of the task isn’t recurring, & there are far too many machines involved to setup one-off schedules in task manager. 

Once deployed via a third party system, the batch executes & the task is finished, with a success code reported.

Though, due to processing & network delays, it’s possible to arrive or try to run on some later than desired. 

The point of the timeframe is to ensure the machines will not be interrupted beyond the available window, & then return an error code of 1, for future targeting. 

The batch does work fine, but not for AM times & I don’t understand why.

Comment: a) what's your `%time%` looks like? b) numbers with leading zeros are handled as octal. `08` and `09` are invalid octal numbers, so your `if`'s will fail. c) logical failure: Let's say it's 01:30 (AM). That's well in the timeslot you want it to run. `1` is less than 23, so shouldrun=False. Just one `if` (`IF "%hour%" geq "02" SET "shouldrun=False" else SET "shouldrun=True"`) should work better. *Every* hour of the day is `LEQ 23`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working correctly:

```
@echo off
SET hour=%time:~0,2%
SET shouldrun=True

IF %hour% GEQ 02 IF %hour% LEQ 19 SET shouldrun=False

IF "%shouldrun%"=="False" (
        echo Outside Update Schedule
        EXIT /B 1
)

IF "%shouldrun%"=="True" (
        @TASKKILL /f /im some.exe > nul 2>&1
        @timeout /t 4 > nul
         - do things here -
        @timeout /t 2 > nul
        shutdown -r -f -y -t 2
        EXIT /B 0
)
```

Comment: For some reason on Windows 10, I had to remove the leading zero on GEQ 02 to GEQ 2.

The leading zero caused it not to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@echo off & setlocal  ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::takes the current hour independent of the time format
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /value`) do for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%i") do set "%%#"
set "hour=%LocalDateTime:~6,2%"

::removes the leading zeroes
cmd /c exit /b %hour%
set hour=%errorlevel%

::checks if should run
if !hour! LEQ 23 if !hour! GEQ 2  (
        echo Outside Update Schedule
        EXIT /B 1
)

echo ---RUNNING----
::your code here. Second if is not needed.
```

Comment: at which time do you expect `if !hour! LEQ 23` to return FALSE?

Comment: @Stephan - you are correct ,but I was just following the logic of the OP. The hour can be changed. in the future.

Comment: valid point. At least, this works. Nice trick to remove the leading zero, btw. Slower than `set /a hour=1%hour%-100`, but that doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to consider [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) for this then I'd do it using a different class, so that I do not have issues with leading zeros, and without needing a for loop either.

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_LocalTime Where "Hour < 2" | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "\<0\> \<1\>" 1>NUL 2>&1 || Echo Exit /B 1
@Rem Your line(s) here
```